# Android: TextView not showing

Tags: android, textview, tablerow

I'm trying to add TableRow dynamically depend on the request I got from server but when I run the application no thing happened else the table header push from right.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void getClientTransaction(JSONArray transactionsArrayInfo)
{
    int transactionsArraySize = transactionsArrayInfo.length();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < transactionsArraySize ; i++ )
    {

        final String senderID = transactionDetails.getString("src_mymoid");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(Transactions.this);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    TextView senderIDTextView = new TextView(Transactions.this);
                    senderIDTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    senderIDTextView.setId(100);
                    senderIDTextView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    senderIDTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    senderIDTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    senderIDTextView.setText(senderID);

                    row.addView(senderIDTextView);
                    transactions_table.addView(row , new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                                           
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the import for your LayoutParams?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the native layout params for action bar instead of using that use the layoutparams for tablerow.

**Solution**

Change the import to

```
android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams
```